# Class that extends RealmObject as a singleton

Tags: java, android, constructor, singleton, realm

I have a configuration class within my Android application that I store within a Realm database. I just edited it to follow the singleton design pattern so there is only ever once instance of the configuration.

The problem is, the class now has a private constructor to prevent instantiation without calling my 'getInstance' method. However, RealmObject seems to require a public constructor.

Is it not possible to have a class that extends RealmObject using a singleton design pattern?

Is this simply a limitation of Realm that I am going to have to account for?

Here is a snippet of code for context:

```
public static  AppConfiguration getInstance(){
    if(configuration == null){
        synchronized (AppConfiguration.class) {
            if (configuration == null) {
                configuration = new AppConfiguration();
            }
        }
    }
    return configuration;
}

//constructor is private to prevent instantiation without using getInstance, enforces singleton
private AppConfiguration() { //The constructor defined as private which is causing the problem
    this.isRegistered = false;
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually your singleton setup does not make sense in the context of Realm, because you synchronize an unmanaged object (thus allowing "only one thread to access it at once" via mutual exclusion / locking), which brings up the question:

- if the object is unmanaged, then why is it a `RealmObject`? (Realm allows consistency with its MVCC architecture, if you use a detached copy then why use Realm at all for its persistence?)
- if the object *was* managed, then how would you access it from multiple threads? (managed RealmObjects are thread-confined ~ you'd need to make it ThreadLocal, and clear it out when its Realm is closed)

---

But yes, you need a public constructor for RealmObject so that Realm can instantiate its proxy instances. Perhaps you can try a `protected` constructor, and see if the RealmProxy can be instantiated via reflection if you do that.

Comment: My thoughts were that I would have a single instance of the object created upon app startup. This single instance would be persisted within Realm, but also be available if I should need to access the instance anywhere else, without having to read it from the Realm database.

I wanted the AppConfiguration to be stored within the Realm database to persist between sessions. Would it make more sense to simply use a Realm stored version and create/read/update/delete from the Realm database when required?

Comment: `also be available if I should need to access the instance anywhere else, without having to read it from the Realm database.` you only read from the Realm when you access the fields, but in reality this is the primary benefit - you always see the same object everywhere. In my opinion, if this synchronization is the way you want to go with it, then you should just persist it to shared preferences as a JSON or something like that, not much point to adding Realm to this object if you're not actually using Realm with it for anything.

Comment: Realm is designed to allow automatic updates for writes to the database that happen on background threads. If you don't listen to changes on this object, and you don't need to keep it managed in order to achieve that, then it might be best to just make it a POJO, right? :p

Comment: You are completely right, I'm trying to wedge singletons and Realm together when they don't fit! I feel I want to stick to using Realm for this (I need to learn how to use it properly!) so I have removed the singleton, and synchronization parts and have set up a DAO for Realm async CRUD on the configuration object. Hopefully this is the right way to go, and I haven't just fell down another rabbit hole!

Comment: Well, check out some articles on my profile page, they might help :)